# MongoDB - DB object or string from MongoClient

Tags: mongodb, database

is there any way to avoid specifying AGAIN the database name when retrieving the collection? I'm already providing that in the uri.

```
String uri = "mongodb://mongodb01dv:27017/myDB" //<-- I'm providing the db here
String db = "myDB"

MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(
  new MongoClientURI(uri))

MongoCollection collection = mongoClient
  .getDatabase(db) //<--- I'm providing the db here again
  .getCollection("myCollection")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDb makes a distinction between `dbname` in the connection string `/database` vs `MongoClient` `getDatabase`.

The `/database` provided in the connection string is optional and only used when connection string contains authentication credentials and authentication is enabled.

The `dbname` provided as part of `getDatabase(dbname)` on `MongoClient` is where application collections are stored.

So to answer your question you can just provide the `dbname` in the `getDatabase` method as you don't have any authentication enabled.

More information

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/